# AngularJs ui-router current state is empty when reload the browser (press F5)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

My issue is that when i enter the route in the browser addressbar or press the F5 button  i allways redirected to 'workspace' beacause the $state.current is allways empty like this:

```
 { name: "", url: "^", views: null, abstract: true }
```

This is my  app.run method

```
 var dependencies = ['smart-table', 'angular-loading-bar', 'ui.router',....]
 var app = ng.module('myApp', dependencies);  
 app
    .run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', '$location',
        'nc.bpt.authentication.services.authenticationService', 'modularity.services.widgetService',
        function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $location, authenticationService, mainMenuService) {

            $rootScope.$state = $state;
            $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;

            $rootScope.$on('unauthorized', function (event, rejection) {
                $state.go('login');
            });

            $rootScope.$on('loginStatusChanged', function (event, authContext) {
                if (authContext.isAuthenticated) {

                    mainMenuService.build(authContext.roles);


                    if (!$state.current.name || $state.current.name === 'login') {
                        $state.go('workspace');
                    }

                } else {
                    $state.go('login');
                }
            });

            authenticationService.fillAuthData();
        }]);
```

Now the Main Controller:

```
ng.module('myApp.controllers')
    .controller('myApp.controllers.appController', ['$scope', '$state','$urlRouter',
        function ($scope, $state, $urlRouter) {
            $scope.authenticated = false;
            $scope.currentState = $state.current.name;
            pushNotificationService.run();

            $scope.$on('unauthorized', function (event, rejection) {
                $scope.authenticated = false;
            });

            $scope.$on('loginStatusChanged', function (event, authContext) {
                $scope.authenticated = authContext.isAuthenticated;
            });

            $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                $scope.currentState = toState.name;
                $urlRouter.sync();
            });
        }]);
```

Now then States:

```
ng.module('myApp.tenancy')
    .config(['$stateProvider',
        function ($stateProvider) {

            $stateProvider
                .state('tenants', {
                    abstract: true,
                    url: 'administration/tenants',
                    template: '<ui-view/>'                   
                })
                .state('tenants.list', {
                    url: '/',
                    templateUrl: '$(Platform)/Scripts/Components/tenancy/views/tenant-list.html'
                })
                .state('tenants.details', {
                    url: '/:id',
                    templateUrl: '$(Platform)/Scripts/Components/tenancy/views/tenant-detail.html'
                })
                .state('tenants.edit', {
                    url: '/:id',
                    templateUrl: '$(Platform)/Scripts/Components/tenancy/views/tenant-edit.html'
                })
                .state('tenants.create', {
                    url: '/create',
                    templateUrl: '$(Platform)/Scripts/Components/tenancy/views/tenant-create.html'
                })
        }]);
```

Comment: I don't see a 'workspace' state. Is it missing?

Comment: sry this state is in other file
                $stateProvider.state('workspace', {
                    url: '/workspace',
                    templateUrl: '$(Platform)/Scripts/Components/workspace/views/workspace.html'
                });